# Run a Windows command line from ASP Classic and get results

Tags: asp-classic, command-line-interface

I'm trying to improve security on an old ASP Classic site.  I need to generate (truly) random numbers, and ASP itself doesn't seem to have that capability directly.  So it occurred to me that I might run a Windows CLI script and use the results.

I've figured out how to run a script, but not how to return the results of that script to ASP.

```
Dim oShell, sCommand
sCommand = "C:\scripts\myscript.bat /foo"
Set oShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = oShell.exec(sCommand)
...?
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Can anybody help me with that last piece of the puzzle.

(Or... if you know a better way to generate truly random numbers in ASP Classic, that would be excellent)

Comment: What's wrong with `Randomize()` and `Rnd()`?

Comment: @Lankymart -- If I run them 10 times in a row, it returns the same "random" number.  Not very random.

Comment: In which case your doing it wrong, show us how you are calling it in your question. Ref - [INFO: How Visual Basic Generates Pseudo-Random Numbers for the RND Function](http://web.archive.org/web/20141027022538/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231847)

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the random number?

Comment: creating nonces for CSP headers

Comment: Okay, I got Rnd working.  Not sure what I was doing wrong -- probably not running randomize first.  Thanks.  (As an exercise, it would still be interesting to return the results of a Windows Batch file... ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Make the output of command redirected to text file. For example "dir >test.txt". Then read the file.